# Merging h1 block with p tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new and stylizing my page with css, is there anyway to combine these two so it's the same without the gap in between (see img below)

code:

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-color: rgba(77, 48, 40, 1);
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
}

p{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>*Home Page*</h1>
<p>Main content</p>
```

[problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1xXb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

it is because `h1` and `p` margin, `h1` default margin bottom is following its font so you should add `margin-bottom:0px;` to h1

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-color: rgba(77, 48, 40, 1);
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;

  margin-bottom:0px;
}

 p{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
  
  margin-top:0px;
}
```

```html
 <h1>*Home Page*</h1>
 <p>Main content</p>
```

if you want to put `h1` and `p` in one box, you should wrap it with element

```css
h1{
  font-size: 80px;
}

 p{
  font-size: 50px;
}
div{

  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <h1>*Home Page*</h1>
 <p>Main content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can choose this as the accepted answer by clicking the ✔ button @Ccarver80

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-color: rgba(77, 48, 40, 1);
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
}

p{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>*Home Page*</h1>
<p>Main content</p>
```